# RTK query - Query lazyload and cache data append problem

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm facing problem while trying to append a cached data with a new data in rtk query. The api is paginated and I want to append the data with the previous data.

If I hardcode the query

```
    loadPosts: builder.query<DefaultResponse<FetchedPostDataType[]>, undefined>(
      {
        query: () => ({
          url: '/diary/648391e4838df5201b4e85e8/all-posts',
          method: 'GET',
          params: {
            page: 1,
          },
        }),

        providesTags: ['DiaryFeed'],
      },
    ),
```

like this only then I can update it's cache using

```
 loadPaginatedPosts: builder.query<
      DefaultResponse<FetchedPostDataType[]>,
      {
        diaryId: string;
        page: number;
      }
    >({
      query: ({diaryId, page}: {diaryId: string; page: number}) => ({
        // query: page => ({
        // url: '/diary/648391e4838df5201b4e85e8/all-posts',
        url: `/diary/${diaryId}/all-posts`,
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          page: page,
        },
      }),

      onQueryStarted: async (arg, {dispatch, queryFulfilled}) => {
        try {
          const {data} = await queryFulfilled;

          dispatch(
            diaryApiSlice.util.updateQueryData('loadPosts', arg, draft => {
              draft.data.push(...data.data);
            }),
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error', error);
        }
      },
    }),
```

But if it's dynamic and has arg like this

```
    loadPosts: builder.query<
      DefaultResponse<FetchedPostDataType[]>,
      {
        diaryId: string;
        page: number;
      }
    >({
      query: ({diaryId, page}: {diaryId: string; page: number}) => ({
        url: `/diary/${diaryId}/all-posts`,
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          page: page,
        },
      }),

      providesTags: ['DiaryFeed'],
    }),
```

then it doesn't work anymore.

I also tried

```
   providesTags: (result, error, {diaryId, page}) => {
     return [{type: 'DiaryFeed', diaryId, page}];
   },
```

Tried dispatching the updateQueryData using args and even with hardcoded arg

```
    dispatch(
            diaryApiSlice.util.updateQueryData(
              'loadPosts',
              {diaryId: arg.diaryId, page: arg.page}, // also tried by giving hardcoded page number
              draft => {
                draft.data.push(...data.data);
              },
            ),
          );
```

I'm not understanding the cache mechanism of RTK query even after going through the documentation. It'll be a great if anyone can help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what you are really trying to do and what the issue is. Each query should be cached on its own by default based on the params passed to it. The `providesTags` where the query Id and page seems fine. Can you [edit] and clarify what the issue is and what the goal is you are wanting to accomplish?

Comment: Suppose, I'm getting post [1,2,3] from page 1, when I'll query for page 2 I want to append the data with the page 1 data like [1,2,3,4,5,6] and when I do any CRUD operations I want to update the individual data from cache data too

Comment: Are you trying to do some sort of "infinite loader" UI where instead of displaying paginated data you are continually appending new data to the end of what's being rendered? It might be better to handle this in normal redux outside RTKQ.

Comment: Yeah. I'm planning to make an infinite list. 

So you're suggesting me to use Axios for api calls and Redux to handle the caching manually?

Comment: No, something more like continuing to use RTK-Query for the API calls and caching, and dispatch all the fetched data to a state slice reducer that holds *all* the fetched data from a `onQueryStarted` handler.

Comment: I thought about this but then thought maybe I'll be over complecating everything by doing so. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll give it a try

Comment: So do you think it's possible doing it using `createEntityAdapter` of redux toolkit?

Comment: It might be possible, but I have never used RTKQ entities. From what I've understood of them it's more of a way to normalize fetched data. I'm just suggesting to use a regular RTK state slice to cache fetched data that when new data is fetched it is added/modified to the existing state, e.g. appended/updated. This is typically how you'd "persist" the fetched data outside the query management.

Comment: Got it. Just like the old school methods. Thanks